# Erro 403 - API Google - Classroom

Tags: python, django, google-api, http-status-code-403

Tenho um script em python que cria e vincula os alunos de uma determinada lista as turmas do Class room no Google via API.

O problema que estou tendo é o seguinte, o aluno e inserido em mais de uma turma na primeira turma ele me acusa o erro 403 que seria de permissão, só que já pra próxima turma ele já passa corretamente, então as autenticações estão corretas queria saber oque pode ta causando esse conflito somente na primeira turma.

Error: {'error': {'code': 403, 'message': 'The caller does not have permission', 'status': 'PERMISSION_DENIED'}}

Função de Inserção :

```
def Insert_Aluno_Turma(idCurso,body):
    url = "%s/%s/students?key=%s" % (URL_COURSES,idCurso,API)
    credentials = get_credentials()
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % credentials.token,
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
    response = requests.post(url,headers=headers,json=body)
    print(response.json())
    return response
```

Já testei com alunos diferente com Turmas diferentes e o erro persiste sempre na primeira turma que o aluno vai ser inserido após ter sido criado ele acusa o erro permissão, mais nas próximas já passa corretamente.